# Difference between GNU and zsh time commands

Tags: bash, time, zsh, gnu

I'm trying to use the max memory output from the GNU and zsh `time` commands and am trying to reconcile the differences I'm seeing in the output. My ultimate goal is to capture the peak RAM usage for a program that is running different sized datasets. To use the zsh I've been following [this example](https://superuser.com/a/767491).

```
$ zsh -i -c 'time ls' > hold
ls --color=auto   0.00s  user 0.00s system 40% cpu 0.002 total
avg shared (code):         0 KB
avg unshared (data/stack): 0 KB
total (sum):               0 KB
max memory:                0 MB
page faults from disk:     0
other page faults:         335
```

With GNU time, I get this...

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M ls > hold
3632
```

I *think* this GNU time is telling me that `ls` used 3.6 KB of RAM, but the zsh version used none. When I repeat this for meatier commands, I also get differences...

```
$zsh -i -c 'time program > hold'
program  > hold   16.36s  user 0.64s system 99% cpu 17.063 total
avg shared (code):         0 KB
avg unshared (data/stack): 0 KB
total (sum):               0 KB
max memory:                94 MB
page faults from disk:     0
other page faults:         25361
```

When I watch the top screen, it looks like the RES column does peak out at 94 MB although the VIRT column is at 127 MB. By GNU time...

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M my_program > hold
387088
```

Or ~387 MB.

Can anyone help me figure out why there are the differences and what I'm missing here?

Comment: The output format of the *zsh* `time` does not look to be the default setting. What is the value of `TIMEFMT` (`echo $TIMEFMT`)?

Comment: It is the same as is described here: http://superuser.com/questions/480928/is-there-any-command-like-time-but-for-memory-usage/767491#767491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think zsh has a time command. Could be wrong, but `-c` looks like "run this shell command", so it's searching your path for `time` and probably finding the same `/usr/bin/time` you're running in bash.

The likely difference is in the formatting. Try passing the same `-f` to the zsh invocation.

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html doesn't show time as a built in. You're running the sane command both ways (depending on what's in your path).

Comment: Time is a zsh command (not sure why it isn't listed):
`> which time
    time: shell reserved word`

Running `disable -r time` will stop it from being used